# Drawing rounded polygon with OpenLayers 3

Tags: automatic-ref-counting, openlayers, polygon, geometry

I need to draw a polygon on my Openlayers 3 map. Part of its border is rounded (half-circle). Is there a way how to specify such an arc or do I have to draw arc using sin/cos approach? Marek

Comment: You will need to use sin/cos. There is no function to create an arc in OpenLayers. There is a regular polygon function that will create a regular polygon of any number of sides, which can be used to approximate a circle, but not a semi circle. It would be trivial to modify this code to do what you need, though: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/lib/OpenLayers/Geometry/Polygon.js#L240

Comment: :( OK, thanks. As my polygons are quite geo-huge, I am afraid of performance issue. I'll try it.

Comment: You only need about 20 points for decent circle approximation. OL3 has a circle class that just stores center point and radius. I haven't looked into how it renders yet.

Comment: Sry, but I don't agree - for example, I have one arc with radius about 130km. Can u imagine 20 points and user having detailed zoom? It'll be far far away from a circle shape .... And, as it is aeronautical application, it has to be precise.

Comment: what does this have to do with automatic ref counting!? So much for ARC.